# Magento Custom options - custom dropdown

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento and I have several questions.
My main question is : Is there a way to create your own custom dropdown menu in Catalog - Product - Custom options.
I have heard that magento is very open sourced and that you can do a lot in it to make it the way you want but I can't seem to find the file which I need to edit to create my custom dropdown menu.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Categories') ?></h4>
    </div>
    <fieldset id="grop_fields">
        <input type="hidden" name="category_ids" id="product_categories" value="<?php echo $this->getIdsString() ?>">
        <div id="product-categories" class="tree"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<?php if($this->getRootNode() && $this->getRootNode()->hasChildren()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.EventManager.onDocumentReady(function() {
    var categoryLoader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
       dataUrl: '<?php echo $this->getLoadTreeUrl()?>'
    });

    categoryLoader.createNode = function(config) {
        config.uiProvider = Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI;
        var node;
        if (config.children && !config.children.length) {
            delete(config.children);
            node = new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode(config);

        } else {
            node = new Ext.tree.TreeNode(config);
        }
        return node;
    };

    categoryLoader.on("beforeload", function(treeLoader, node) {
        treeLoader.baseParams.category = node.attributes.id;
    });

    categoryLoader.on("load", function(treeLoader, node, config) {
        varienWindowOnload();
    });

    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel('product-categories', {
        animate:true,
        loader: categoryLoader,
        enableDD:false,
        containerScroll: true,
        rootUIProvider: Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI,
        selModel: new Ext.tree.CheckNodeMultiSelectionModel(),
        rootVisible: '<?php echo $this->getRootNode()->getIsVisible() ?>'
    });

    tree.on('check', function(node) {
        if(node.attributes.checked) {
            categoryAdd(node.id);
        } else {
            categoryRemove(node.id);
        }
        varienElementMethods.setHasChanges(node.getUI().checkbox);
    }, tree);

    // set the root node
    var root = new Ext.tree.TreeNode({
        text: '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getRootNode()->getName()) ?>',
        draggable:false,
        checked:'<?php echo $this->getRootNode()->getChecked() ?>',
        id:'<?php echo $this->getRootNode()->getId() ?>',
        disabled: <?php echo ($this->getRootNode()->getDisabled() ? 'true' : 'false') ?>,
        uiProvider: Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI
    });

    tree.setRootNode(root);
    bildCategoryTree(root, <?php echo $this->getTreeJson() ?>);
    tree.addListener('click', categoryClick.createDelegate(this));

    // render the tree
    tree.render();
    root.expand();
    //tree.expandAll();
});

function bildCategoryTree(parent, config){
    if (!config) return null;

    if (parent && config && config.length){
        for (var i = 0; i < config.length; i++){
            config[i].uiProvider = Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI;
            var node;
            var _node = Object.clone(config[i]);
            if (_node.children && !_node.children.length) {
                delete(_node.children);
                node = new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode(_node);

            } else {
                node = new Ext.tree.TreeNode(config[i]);
            }
            parent.appendChild(node);
            node.loader = node.getOwnerTree().loader;
            if(config[i].children){
                bildCategoryTree(node, config[i].children);
            }
        }
    }
}

function categoryClick(node, e){
    if (node.disabled) {
        return;
    }
    node.getUI().check(!node.getUI().checked());
    varienElementMethods.setHasChanges(Event.element(e), e);
};
function categoryAdd(id) {
    var ids = $('product_categories').value.split(',');
    ids.push(id);
    $('product_categories').value = ids.join(',');
}
function categoryRemove(id) {
    var ids = $('product_categories').value.split(',');
    // bug #7654 fixed
    while (-1 != ids.indexOf(id)) {
        ids.splice(ids.indexOf(id), 1);
    }
    $('product_categories').value = ids.join(',');
}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you `should not`. You can do anything using this.

But as per your need you should edit this file.

`app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template->catalog->product->edit->options.phtml`

And if you need to go deep, then goto `options folder` in the same position.

Comment: So i got to that file and looked trough it for several times and i didnt see anything that would even refer to a dropdown wich i need to change to make it custom.

Comment: Have you checked the backend..there you need to select what type of input field you want in frontend. Like radio,dropdown,textbox,checkbox,multiselect etc.After selecting type of field you need to add options there. So you can easily select input type "dropdown" and add options to that. You just wanted to find the files hence i tell you the file names.

Comment: Ill put the file in the question maybe that you can find something (if you want to) it but I coudn't.

Comment: check the path properly..its not that file

Comment: check this `app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template->catalog->product->edit->options.phtml` and `app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template->catalog->product->edit->options->option.phtml`

Comment: Oops, my bad. Got the right file now thank you.
Any chance that you have some examples of custom dropdown menus?